# Weblogic Error : org/mozilla/javascript/CompilerEnvirons

Tags: java, javascript, jar, weblogic, mozilla

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class 
org/mozilla/javascript/DefaultErrorReporter from class org/mozilla/javascript/CompilerEnvirons
at org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.(CompilerEnvirons.java:48)
at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:310)
at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
at com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil._minifyJavaScript(MinifierUtil.java:80)
at com.liferay.portal.util.MinifierUtil.minifyJavaScript(MinifierUtil.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.strip(StripFilter.java:248)
at
```

I am encountering that error. I am using Weblogic 10.3

I have my rhino-js-1.6R7.jar in my jdk path which is included in my classpath. but still encounters that problem

How should I go with this? Thanks!